# PHP while loops and tables

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I'm having trouble getting this into one table. Right now I am using two tables and having them side by side but I don't think that is the best solution. I have the table all set up I just can't figure out how to get this into one.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

$result .= "<tr> <td> {$row['a']} the {$row['b']} </td>      </tr>";
 }

  echo $thegames;
```

This produces something like:

```
       james the giant
       rick the monster
       chris the goblin
```

What I want is to be able to add more tds from a separate while loop...

```
  while($secondrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($secondquery)) { 
   $first = "<td> {$secondrow['alias']} </td>";
   $second = "<td> {$secondrow['number']} </td>";
  }
```

So in the end I would like it would look like this:

```
   james the giant $secondrow['alias']  $secondrow['number'] 
   rick the monster $secondrow['alias']  $secondrow['number']
```

etc...

Hope this makes sense. What I'm doing now is creating two separate tables and trying to line them up but don't like that method. Any help would be great.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your code, you don't actually need to do two queries. If you are expecting 4 columns for each row, there's no need to do multiple while loops either. Rather, a change in the structure of your query to use a JOIN; that will enable you to get the full result set in one shot.

As it has been mentioned, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated.

I'll show you how to do a JOIN with PDO, making some assumptions about your table names and primary keys based on the code you've shown so far:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", '-username-', '-password-');
$sql = '
    SELECT 
        `players`.`id`, 
        `players`.`a`,
        `players`.`b`, 
        `player_info`.`alias`,
        `player_info`.`number`   
    FROM 
        `players` 
    LEFT JOIN
        `player_info` ON  `players`.id = `player_info`.`player_id`
';
$players = $pdo->query($sql);

$row_data= array();
while ($row = $players->fetch()) {
    $row_data[] = '
        <td>'.$row->a.' the '.$row->b.'</td>
        <td>'.$row->alias.'</td>
        <td>'.$row->number.'</td>   
    ';
}

echo '<table><tr>'.implode('</tr><tr>', $row_data).'</tr></table'>;
```

If the join proves to be impractical (not typical), then you should build your data array and generate the HTML as two seperate steps:

```
// gather the data
$data = array();
$first = $pdo->query($sql);
while($arow = $first->fetch()) {
    $one_data['a'] = $arow->a;
    $one_data['b'] = $arow->b;

    $second = $pdo->query($second_sql);
    while($brow = $second->fetch()) {
        $one_data['alias'] = $brow->alias;
        $one_data['number'] = $brow->number;
    }
    $data[] = $one_data;
}

// now generate HTML
print '<table>';
foreach ($data as $row) {
    print '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['a'].' the '.$row['b'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['alias'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['number'].'</td> 
        </tr>
    ';
}
print '</table>';
```

And as a side note... columns named `a` and `b` are just a **bad**. **idea**. Those columns represent data, so give them labels that reflect what that data is. Dealing with mystery columns TODAY might be fine... you remember what they mean. 6 months from now? A year from now? Use meaningful names for all columns and variables -- why not?

**Documentation**

- `PDO` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php
- `PDO::query` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
- `PDOStatement` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php
- `PDOStatement::fetch` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
- `mysql_query` **DEPRECATED!** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- mySQL `JOIN` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer... could be a dumb question but to start using PDO do I need to download anything or switch from MAMP?

Comment: You need to ensure you have the MySQL PDO drivers. It ships standard with most stacks like MAMP, though I am not familiar with that one specifically. If not, it is typically easy to add. Check your `phpinfo`, you should see a PDO section, and mysql should be listed in the drivers.

Comment: sweet. thanks I found it and its enabled. Guess I'll start learning that stuff. Thanks mane.

Comment: No problem! If you're just starting out with PHP, you're actually better off than someone who already learned the old way and now has to break a habit: you get to start off on the right foot. The important and BIG difference with PDO is the `prepare` method, be sure to read the docs on that. You don't build your variables into queries by combining strings with PDO like you do with `mysql_`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your 2 sets into 1 array and loop over that while printing.

edit; someone found this a bad answer, but that means that you agree with the above result which puts fetching sql rows in your template.

You first prepare your data for the template and THEN you loop over it and print it.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but it isn't necessary or helpful to reference or denigrate other answers to support your own.

Comment: At any rate, as I mentioned in my answer, I edited to improve. One of the approaches I suggested is what I believe you are advising here, so a +1 from me.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what I meant +1